# Rom-sql Rake Task

Tags: rake, roda, rom-sql

I'm trying to setup migrations using 'rom/sql/rake_task'.

Here is my sample, but sadly it isn't working as it's complaining about a missing sequel adaptor. Any assistance or direction would be appreciated?

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'rom-sql'
require 'rom/sql/rake_task'

namespace :db do
  task :setup do
    ROM.setup(:sql, 'sqlite_memory')
    ROM.finalize

    ROM::SQL.migration do
      change do
        create_table(:users) do
          primary_key :id
          String :name
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete example: https://github.com/gotar/sinatra-rom

after you add

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rom/sql/rake_task'

task :setup do
  # Load ROM related stuff. You don't need to specify manually connection
end
```

to Rakefile you will get few Raketasks (rake -T) to list them,

and then

```
$ rake db:create_migration[any_name]
```

and in file it will create, you can add your migration.

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna try:

```
ROM::SQL::Migration.connection = ROM.setup(:sql, 'sqlite_memory').default.connection
ROM.finalize.env

ROM::SQL::Migration.create do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks @squixy - but I am still getting LoadError: cannot load such file -- sequel/adapters/

Comment: Which version of ROM are you using?

Comment: Using roda 2.2.0
Using transproc 0.2.0
Using rom 0.6.2
Using sequel 4.22.0
Using rom-sql 0.4.1

Comment: this is the directions I was following, http://rom-rb.org/blog/2015/04/04/rom-0-6-1-released/